# Centos: there are many 'httpd start' process

Tags: linux, apache, centos, httpd.conf

I found that my server is very slow,I used 'ps au' to show all the processes. There are a lot of `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start` running.

How could I fix this problem?

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0 195536 10040 ?        Ss   6月11  40:57 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --d
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    6月11   0:00 [kthreadd]
nobody   31295  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31296  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31297  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31299  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31303  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31310  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31312  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31314  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31315  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31316  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31320  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31324  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31326  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31328  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31329  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31330  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31331  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31332  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31333  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31335  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31338  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31339  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31341  0.0  0.0  97160  6208 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31346  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31364  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31370  0.0  0.0  97028  5036 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31373  0.0  0.0  97028  5040 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31374  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31416  0.0  0.0  97028  5048 ?        S    11:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31418  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31422  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31423  0.0  0.0  97028  5044 ?        S    11:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
dovecot  31461  0.0  0.0  27940  2232 ?        S    11:04   0:00 dovecot/auth
root     31525  0.0  0.0  82012 11368 ?        S    11:04   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl /usr/local/cpanel/
nobody   31578  0.0  0.0  97028  4800 ?        S    11:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
nobody   31579  0.0  0.0  97028  5048 ?        S    11:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with Apache servers and A LOT of httpd processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922194/problems-with-apache-servers-and-a-lot-of-httpd-processes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use process control the worker by using the following directives:

- ServerLimit         16
- StartServers         2
- MaxRequestWorkers  150
- MinSpareThreads     25
- MaxSpareThreads     75
- ThreadsPerChild     25

Set values accordingly.